# how to convert word file to pdf file using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

There is any way to convert a word file to a pdf file using Flutter web?

i try docx and pdf packages but it not support word file to a pdf file converter.

Comment: I know Gembox has a tool to do this, not sure if its inherent flutter or dart code though.

Comment: it support only c# language

Comment: Not ONLY, but it does support C# and thus Asp.NET and the like, BUT it also has legacy support of ASP Classic and other languages.    If you want one "built for flutter" then I don't think that is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter web does not have native support for converting Word files to PDF files. However, you may be able to use third-party APIs or libraries to accomplish this task.

One option is to use a cloud-based API service like Cloudmersive Document Conversion API, which allows you to convert Word files to PDF files programmatically through REST API calls. You can use the http package in Flutter to make HTTP requests to the API and get the converted PDF file as a response.

Another option is to use a server-side PDF conversion library like LibreOffice or Ghostscript, and make an HTTP request from your Flutter web app to your server-side code to perform the conversion. You could use the http package in Flutter to make the request and receive the converted PDF file as a response.

Don't forget these options require you to have access to an external server or API, and may incur additional costs.

Comment: This works for non-sensitive or non-U/L scenarios where data security is not critical.  But if you need to do it in house, my comment above about Gembox is one solution, but there are others that you could host on your own systems and convert the data locally, instead of relying on the cloud service to do this for you.

Comment: there is option to use library like LibreOffice without a server-side.

Answer (score -1):

You can use third-party API to do that. One of them which is very easy is ApyHub's Word to PDF Conversion API.

Here's a code for which uses this API:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() async {
  final params = {
    'output': 'test-sample.pdf',
    'landscape': 'false',
  };

  final url = Uri.parse('https://api.apyhub.com/convert/word-file/pdf-file')
      .replace(queryParameters: params);

  final req = http.MultipartRequest('POST', url)
    ..files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath(
      'file', 'test.doc'));

  req.headers['apy-token'] = 'YOUR-SECRET-TOKEN';
  req.headers['content-type'] = 'multipart/form-data';

  final stream = await req.send();
  final res = await http.Response.fromStream(stream);
  final status = res.statusCode;
  if (status != 200) throw Exception('http.send error: statusCode= $status');

  print(res.body);
}
```

You can generate `secret-apy-token` from [here](https://apyhub.com/utility/converter-doc-pdf) ( It's free and offer up to 2M API Calls in starter plan)